# The path of the file that contains the IP address in mac

Tags: networking

where can I find the file that contains the IP address of the DNS server that i use in my mac?

**I tried the folder /Network but there is nothing in it.**

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` or `/var/run/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Question would be better asked on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Use `scutil --dns` to see how DNS is configured in macOS. Also look into `networksetup -getdnsservers` and `networksetup -setdnsservers` (and `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`).

Modern macOS has a sophisticated "scoped routing" subsystem for DNS queries, controlled by the "System Configuration" system (configd, scutil, scselect), as well as mDNSResponder. This is to help deal with modern networking scenarios like when you have a VPN connection to your work, and DNS queries pertaining to your work's domain names and IP addresses need to go down the VPN tunnel, but all other DNS queries should not go via the VPN tunnel.

To support old Unix tools (and old Unix nerds) that expect to find a DNS server IP address listed in /etc/resolv.conf, macOS still has that file, but it is autogenerated by the more modern subsystems I mentioned above. Editing that file won't change how your system's main DNS resolver subsystem is configured. Editing that file will probably only change what DNS server is used by old Unix tools for DNS debugging that contain their own DNS resolver code instead of relying on system calls (so things like `nslookup(1)` and `dig(1)` and maybe `host(1)`).